# Does that the current draft permit to form an overload set that consists of two non-static member declarations where one has ref-qualifier

Tags: c++, overloading, language-lawyer, c++23

The [basic.scope#scope-3.3.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#scope-3.3.1) says

> both declare functions with the same parameter-type-list, equivalent ([temp.over.link]) trailing requires-clauses (if any, except as specified in [temp.friend]), and, if both are non-static members, the same cv-qualifiers (if any) **and** ref-qualifier (if both have one)

The above rule could be understood to,  For two non-static member functions with the same parameter-type-list, if anyone has a cv-qualifiers then both declarations should have the same cv-qualifiers; if both declarations have ref-qualifier, they should have the same ref-qualifier. Otherwise, they do not correspond.

```cpp
struct A{
    void show();  //#1
    void show() const &;  //#2
};
```

In this snippet, Does #1 correspond to #2? Since #2 has a cv-qualifier but #1 does not have, even if the condition for having the same  `ref-qualifier` is true, as per the rule(note the emphasized **and**  in that rule), they do not correspond. So, Does it mean that the draft permits to form an overload set from such two declarations? After all, the section [over.load#2.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.load#2.3) was removed by P1787.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This change was an inadvertent result of [phrasing the rules more orthogonally](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html), but since that orthogonality allows a few additional meaningful overload sets, there hasn’t been any hurry to “fix” it.  In particular, it might work well with the [proposal for deducing `this`](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r6.html) that’s currently under consideration.

Comment: Does that mean the above example is well-formed in the current standard?

Comment: @xmh0511: Yes, it is (though I believe the *ref-qualifier* has no effect in this particular case).

Comment: *though I believe the ref-qualifier has no effect in this particular case* Absolutely, according to your confirmation, in the current draft, whether one of the declarations in the example has a `ref-qualifier` or not, it does not affect the result that the two declarations do not correspond(since they do not have the same cv-qualifier). However, in the older standard(Specifically, [over.load#2.3]), adding the ref-qualifier to one of the declarations(but not both) will make the example be ill-formed. Hence, in order to emphasize the case, I adopted the above example comes here.

Comment: @xmh0511: The point of "no effect" is that **this** *ref-qualifier* doesn't affect overload resolution (or the validity of the function body).

Comment: The re-qualifier affect the overload set in the past. For instance, `struct A{
    void show() &{} //#1
    void show(){} //#2
};` In the current draft, the definition for `A` itself is well-formed and `alvalue.show()` should be ambiguous since the implicit parameters are all `A&`. However, in the c++20 standard, the definition of the class `A` is ill-formed itself. The latest [compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/Pfjh3hcoh) does not obey the current draft.